# Getting an error while trying to import query results from VS 2013 to microsoft excel 2013

Tags: excel, tfs

I have VS 2013 installed on my laptop and I am using MS OFFICE 2013. 
I have created queries for tracking tasks in TFS. I am getting an error while trying to open\import the query results in MS EXCEL.

Here is the error that I am getting:

TF400422: Failed to open in Microsoft Excel: Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID 
'{ooo208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from 
HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Excel-Options, click Add-Ins and select COM Add-ins, then click Go to select the checkbox of "Team Foundation Add-in", and click OK to save the change. If you have multiple Versions of the TFS Plugin installed select the appropriate Version. The version number can be identified by the path of the plugin.
2. Try to install 32-bit Office on your machine, and re-register the Office add-in. The command is:

For 64-bit windows: 
`Regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\12.0\amd64\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll"`

For 32-bit windows: 
`Regsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Team Foundation Server\12.0\x86\TFSOfficeAdd-in.dll"`

Replace the `12.0` in the path with the version for of your TFS:

- `11.0` for TFS 2012
- `12.0` for TFS 2013
- `14.0` for TFS 2015
- `15.0` for TFS 15